# Transform a flat list to nested List

Tags: python, recursion

Using Python

I want the following:

```
[1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

To be transformed into:

```
[1, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3], 2, 3]
```

Rules: Go through each item in the list. If we hit a 2 followed by a 1 created a list and include that 1 in that list until we hit a 3, include that 3, then close the list and continue. It's like if 1 was 3 were parenthesis.

I'm not very good with recursive algorithms which I think might be needed in this case.

Thanks as always.

Comment: You're description isn't entirely clear.  If you're going from left to right following your rules, the result would look instead like this: [[1,2,2,1,2,3],2,3].  If you need the lists to nest like parenthesis as you suggest later on, then those rules don't quite work.

Comment: Also, are you guaranteed to have balanced lists?  E.g. will you always see 1,2 at start and 3 at end with the same number of each?  If not, what do you want to see given e.g. [1,2,1,2], [1,2,1,2,3], [3,3,1,2,3,1,3,3]?

Comment: Too many doubts - please give us more samples and describe your requirements in details

Comment: Basically 1 = start, 2 = data, 3 = end. They are balanced lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an entertaining problem! Here is my solution:

```
def treeize(treeizable, tree=None, stopper=object()):
    if tree is None:
        tree = []

    if treeizable[:1] == [stopper]:
        tree.append(treeizable.pop(0))       
        return tree
    elif treeizable[0:2] == [2, 1]:
        tree.append(treeizable.pop(0))
        subtree = []
        treeize(treeizable, subtree, stopper=3)
        tree.append(subtree)
        return treeize(treeizable, tree, stopper)
    elif treeizable:
        tree.append(treeizable.pop(0))
        return treeize(treeizable, tree, stopper)
    else:
        return tree
```

This function receives a flat list `treeizable` that should be converted to a nested list `tree`. The `stopper` parameter marks when the current list is done - being this a nested or the toplevel list. (Since the default value of `stopper` is an instance of `object`, it is impossible that there will be a stopper on a list called with the default value, because instances of `object` are different between themselves).

```
def treeize(treeizable, tree=None, stopper=object()):
```

For easing our work, the default value of `tree` is `None` and, if it has the default value, then it is set to a list. It is made because [it is problematic to have mutable values as default parameter objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/287976). Also, it would be annoying to have to type the function with an empty list everytime.

```
    if tree is None:
        tree = []
```

If the first value of the flat list is the "stopper", then it is added to the tree and the tree is returned. Note that, by using `treeizable.pop(0)` I am actually *removing* the value from the flat list. Since the stopper is only set when defining a nested list so, when we found it, no more need to be done: the "subtree" (that is, the nested list) is complete. Also, note that I get the first element of the list with a slice of the list. I made it because it is boring to have to type `if treeizable and treeizable[0] == stopper`. Since slicing does not have problems with inexistent indexes, I got the slice and compared it to another list made in place with only the stopper:

```
    if treeizable[:1] == [stopper]:
        tree.append(treeizable.pop(0))       
        return tree
```

If the beginning of the list is the "beginner", then I pop the first element from the list, append it to the tree and create a new tree - that is, a empty list. Now I call `treeize()` with the remaining list and the empty subtree, also passing 3 as the stopper value. `treeize()` will recursively generate a new tree that I append to my initial tree. After that, just call `treeize()` with the remaining of the list (which does not contain the elements of the subtree anymore) and the original list. Note that the stopper should be the same stopper received by the original call.

```
    elif treeizable[0:2] == [2, 1]:
        tree.append(treeizable.pop(0))
        subtree = []
        treeize(treeizable, subtree, stopper=3)
        tree.append(subtree)
        return treeize(treeizable, tree, stopper)
```

If none of the previous conditions (the first element is a stopper, the beginning of the list is `[2, 1]`) is true, then I verify if there is something in the list. In this case, I pop the first element, add to the tree and call `treeize()` with the rest of the list.

```
    elif treeizable:
        tree.append(treeizable.pop(0))
        return treeize(treeizable, tree, stopper)
```

In the case that not even the previous condition is true... then we have an empty list. This means that all elements were put in the tree. Just return the tree to the user:

```
    else:
        return tree
```

This seems to have worked:

```
>>> treeize.treeize([1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3,  3, 2, 3, 4])
[1, 2, 2, [1, 2, 2, [1, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3], 2, 4, 5, 3], 3], 2, 3, 4]
```

Your question has a taste of homework. In principle, we should not answer it but it is so interesting that I couldn't help myself :) If it is a homework, however, do not try to use this solution as your because it would be wrong and your teacher would surely find it on Google :P

Comment: This is a really elegant solution. Rest assured this is not homework, but I will be studying this intently. Thanks again for putting in your time and effort into answering my question. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 3):

Still keeping in mind that @Walter is correct in his comments to your question, this is a silly implementation of what you asked for, inspired by the final bit of your question, in which you suggest that `1` and `3` could just be replaced with `[1` and `3]`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = repr([1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3])
>>> s = re.sub('1', '[1', s)
>>> s = re.sub('3', '3]', s)
>>> l = eval(s)
>>> l
[[1, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3], 2, 3]]
```

What it does is working on the representation of the list (a string) and substituting the way you suggested using regular expressions. Finally, it evaluate the string (getting back a list).

I call this implementation "silly" because it does the trick, but it's ugly and truly unpythonic. That said, it does the trick, so if you are simply using it for a one-off conversion of some data you need to use...

HTH!

Comment: Actualy he wrote that list should be inserted when there is a 1 after 2, so there is no need in parenthesis at the begining of the list.

Comment: @mac: have you tried `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`? The result should be the same list, but with your solution it's `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]`.

Comment: @Artsiom @pillmuncher - You are both somehow right, but if you read the comments to the OP's question, you will notice that the question is ambiguous. This is why I began it with _"@Walter is correct in his comments"_ and this is also why I specified that my answer was _"inspired by the final bit..."_ (that says `It's like if 1 and 3 were parenthesis.`). My point in writing the answer even with a question with conflicting specifications was to show how this could be done by using regex, which could be obviously adapted to match any of the behaviours you mentioned in your comments. :)

Comment: @mac - ok I see, +1 - but why not to use simply str.replace? Is there any benifit to use re?

Comment: @Artsiom - in this specific case no, there is no benefit. The reason for which I chose to use regex instead of `replace` is exactly because of the ambiguity of the question: a regex could be easily adapted to include something like "substitute 1 _only if_ it comes after 2". With `replace` that would require an `if`.

Comment: That is a pretty incomplete solution since there can be unbalanced values. You can end with much more `]` than `[` and vice versa and a real could would have to deal with it (which is not difficult at all, BTW). Said that, the originality, simplicity and awesomeness of the concept deserve an upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

```
def whatever(a):
    b = []
    tmp = []
    last = None

    for elem in a:
        if tmp:
            tmp.append(elem)
            if elem == 3:
                b.append(tmp)
                tmp = []
        elif last == 2 and elem == 1:
            tmp.append(1)
        else:
            b.append(elem)
        last = elem
    return b

print whatever([1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I like state machines:

```
from itertools import izip, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b)
    return izip(a, b)

class Flat(object):
    def append_next(self, alist, e0, e1):
        alist.append(e0)
        if e0 == 2 and e1 == 1:
            alist.append([])
            self.__class__ = Nested
    def append_last(self, alist, e):
        alist.append(e)

class Nested(object):
    def append_next(self, alist, e0, e1):
        alist[-1].append(e0)
        if e0 == 3:
            self.__class__ = Flat
    def append_last(self, alist, e):
        alist[-1].append(e)

def nested(flat_list):
    if len(flat_list) <= 1:
        return list(flat_list)
    state = Flat()
    nested_list = []
    for x, y in pairwise(flat_list):
        state.append_next(nested_list, x, y)
    state.append_last(nested_list, y)
    return nested_list

s = [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]

print nested(s)
```

gives:

```
[1, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3], 2, 3]
```

But this might be more pythonic:

```
def nested(flat_list):
    if len(flat_list) <= 1:
        return list(flat_list)
    pairs = pairwise(flat_list)
    nested_list = []
    while True:
        for x, y in pairs:
            nested_list.append(x)
            if x == 2 and y == 1:
                nested_list.append([])
                break
        else:
            nested_list.append(y)
            break
        for x, y in pairs:
            nested_list[-1].append(x)
            if x == 3:
                break
        else:
            nested_list[-1].append(y)
            break
    return nested_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Pease bear with me - it is 2:50(night) - here is my version - not very beatiful but it works pretty well for me:

```
def buildNewList(inputList):
    last = 0
    res = []
    for i,c in enumerate(inputList):
        if i == 0:
            prev = c
        if i < last:
            continue
        if c == 1 and prev == 2:
            if 3 in inputList[i:]:
                last = i + 1 + inputList[i:].index(3)
                res.append(buildNewList(inputList[i: last]))
            else:
                last = len(inputList)
                res.append(buildNewList(inputList[i:len(inputList)]))
        else:
            res.append(c)
        prev = c
    return res


l1 = buildNewList([1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3])
>>> [1, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3], 2, 3]

l2 = buildNewList([1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3])
>>> [1, 2, 2, [1, 2, 3], 2, [1, 2, 3]]

l3 = buildNewList([1,2,3,1,2,3])
>>> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

l4 = buildNewList([1,2,1,1,2,1])
>>> [1, 2, [1, 1, 2, [1]]]
```